# About data transfer one object to array through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
class A
{
   public string[] X {get;set;}
   public string[] Y {get;set;}
}

class B
{
  public string X {get;set;}
  public string Y {get;set;}
}
```

transfer data of A's object to B's array with Linq? suppose Object of A have 10-10 size X and Y and I want to transfer into B array `(B[] b = new B[10])`

```
A a = new A();
//put 10 items in both x and y
B[] b = new B[10];
//here I want to get a's data to b
```

Comment: What is so terrible about using loops directly?

Comment: there is one problem with your question, for writing a query what is the guarantee that both `X` and `Y` in `A` are of same length ?

Comment: How should each `string[]` in `A` be transferred to a `string` in `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method from LINQ:

```
A a = new A();
B[] bs = a.X.Zip(a.Y, (x, y) => new B() { X = x, Y = y })
            .ToArray();
```

Or use `Select` with index:

```
B[] bs = a.X.Select((x, i) => new B {X = x, Y = a.Y[i]})
            .ToArray();
```

Another way using `Enumerable.Range` if you get stuck on .NET 3.5:

```
B[] bs = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                   .Select(i => new B {X = a.X[i], Y = a.Y[i]})
                   .ToArray();
```